# SublimeText linter - stop opening a window with linting errors

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint, sublime-text-plugin

Recently there was an unexpected change to my SublimeText linter. When there is a linting error in the file I'm working in an ST window opens with the linting error.

```
SublimeLinter: #1053 eslint someJSFile.js.jsx ERROR:

Warning: the NODE_ENV is not set and the webpack config is defaulting to a production build.
[{"filePath":"/Users/.../someJSFile.js.jsx","messages":[{"ruleId":"import/extensions","severity":2,"message":"Missing file extension for \"jquery\"","line":2,"column":15,"nodeType":"Literal","source":"import $ from \"jquery\";","endLine":2,"endColumn":23},{"ruleId":"import/no-commonjs","severity":2,"message":"Expected \"export\" or \"export default\"","line":40,"column":1,"nodeType":"MemberExpression","source":"module.exports = ...
```

I'm fine with an inline error as it was displaying, but this is annoying. How can I prevent this window from popping up?

Answer (score -1):

This isn’t a lint error, but rather the linter reporting a configuration error that prevents it from working correctly. We’ve made some improvements to how SublimeLinter deals with those, but if you’re still getting these the meat of the message is this line:

`Warning: the NODE_ENV is not set and the webpack config is defaulting to ..etc`